# Renewal certificate with new key pairs

Tags: python, x509certificate, x509certificate2, certenroll

I want to create CX509CertificateRequestPkcs 
with  initializefromcertificate 
 And i want to use  X509RequestInheritOptions.InheritNewSimilarkey  to generate new keypair where original certificate'key pair exsit
  But i get error  CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestPkcs7::InitializeFromCertificate: The requested property value is empty. 0x80094004 (-2146877436 CERTSRV_E_PROPERTY_EMPTY)"
This is my code

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 c in store.Certificates)
{
    var cert2 = c.Subject;
    if (cert2.Contains("CN=test"))
    {
        var objPkcs72 = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs7();
        string strCertificate = Convert.ToBase64String(c.RawData);
        var inheritOptions = X509RequestInheritOptions.InheritNewSimilarKey ;
        objPkcs72.InitializeFromCertificate(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, false, strCertificate, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, inheritOptions);
        ISignerCertificate signer = new CSignerCertificate();
        CERTENROLLLib.CSignerCertificate signer2 = new CERTENROLLLib.CSignerCertificate();
        signer2.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifyAllowUI, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, strCertificate);
        objPkcs72.SignerCertificate = signer2;
        string c2 = "";
        objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPkcs72);
        var message2 = objEnroll.CreateRequest(EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
        var iDisposition = objCertRequest.Submit(CR_IN_BASE64 | CR_IN_FORMATANY, message2, templateName, CAAddress);
        string c3 = objCertRequest.GetCertificate(CR_IN_BASE64 | CR_IN_FORMATANY);
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(LoadFromCertBase64String(c2));
        objEnroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowNone, c3, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your formatting and [edit] so that this isn't just a giant wall of text. How is tho code you're trying actually formatted?

Comment: @G.Anderson i try to correct it, but i'm using mobile phone and unfortunately i coudn't correct it